# How to initialize a list of map in null aware flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I need an empty list of map in which I wish to add maps one by one based on user actions. I do not know how many maps would be in the list. Before I had used this.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic> _items = new List<Map<String, dynamic>();
```

This doesn't seem to work anymore. I am coding in VS code and it shows error,

> "List constructor not available when null safety is enabled".

So now what is the correct way of implementing this. I need to be able to add maps to this list using .add() method.

Answer (score 0):

`List<Map<String, dynamic> _items = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];`

or `List<Map<String, dynamic> _items = [];`